# Find if given number is perfect square or not?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public boolean isPerfectSquare(int n) {
    int l=1, r=n;
    if(r==l) return true;
    return searchBinary(l, r, n);
}
public boolean searchBinary(int l, int r, int n){
    if(r>l){
        int mid=l+(r-l)/2;
      //  System.out.println(l + " " + r + " " + mid + " " +n);
        if(mid*mid == n) return true;
        else if(mid*mid>n) return searchBinary(l, mid-1, n);
        else return searchBinary(mid+1, r, n);
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code is failing for `n=808201`

I'm not getting why it's not working. This code looks Ok to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "failing" ? Bad result ? Exception? If exception, what is the stacktrace ?

Comment: @OlivierDepriester It gives false output for n=808201

Comment: Usually it's just a matter of changing if r>l into if r>=l. This is for LeetCode daily challenge, isn't it?

Comment: @justhalf Yes, but by changing r>l to r>=l. It won't work.

Comment: Computation of `mid*mid` in `int`  is probably overflowing; try making `mid` a `long` instead.

Comment: @KevinAnderson by making mid as long won't help. b/c i'm not storing mid*mid computation anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Because `mid * mid` exceding int range.

for n=808201, you fail at mid = 300325 , change to long value

```java
public static boolean isPerfectSquare(int n) {
        int l=1, r=n;
        if(r==l) return true;
        return searchBinary(l, r, n);
    }
    public static boolean searchBinary(long l, long r, int n){
        if (l > r) {
            return false;
        }
        long mid=(r + l) >> 1;
        //  System.out.println(l + " " + r + " " + mid + " " +n);
        if(mid*mid == n) return true;
        else if(mid*mid>n) return searchBinary(l, mid-1, n);
        else return searchBinary(mid+1, r, n);
    }
```

Comment: i'm not getting. as ```mid*mid``` is not stored anywhere then why it overflows in mid*mid

Comment: But it **is** being stored.  Somewhere.  Not in any named Java variable, but _somewhere_. And that _somewhere_ is the size of an `int`, because the rules of Java arithmetic say that an `int` multiplied by an `int` gives an `int` result.

Comment: @Nitin, JVM still need a place to store the result of `mid*mid` even though you didn't assign it to a variable otherwise, how can JVM process the comparison between `mid*mid > n`

Comment: @PatrickChen, you mean to say ```mid*mid``` result will be stored as mid=mid*mid in memory?

Comment: @Nitin, yes, JVM works (mid * mid) >n, more like a stack structure, first calculate the `mid*mid` and put the result into memory, then get the result to calculate `result > n`, so it definitely  put the result in the memory.